# Possible to move an object from one .blend to another one?

Tags: modeling, objects

Is it possible to have an object in one .blend file, and move it to a different .blend file?

Example: Say I have a tree I made in one .blend file, and I want to move that tree to a landscape I have saved in a different .blend file.

EDIT: You can also go to File > Export > Wavefront (OBJ) and save it. Then go to original project and go to File > Import > Wavefront (OBJ).

Comment: Yes... File > Apend or Link.

Comment: If you use Append the object becomes independent. I you use Link any changes you make in the original object will effect the linked object(s). It's a great way to start a library of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file into which you want to import the object. Then, click `File > Append` (or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>). Choose the original `.blend` file, where the object is located. When you have chosen a file, you will have to choose what to import. In this case, click "`Mesh`". Then, select the mesh that you want to import.